# Why function size always increase when refreshing it using memory profiler python?

Tags: python, django, memory-profiling

I am using a python memory profiler and at top of every function, I am using `@profile` on top of function to analyze the memory consumption of the function.But every time I refresh the same page the size of my function always increases.Why is it so I don't know.
I tried using python garbage collector but that has no impact.An example of this i am pasting here.

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
    27     83.2 MiB     83.2 MiB   @login_required
    28                             @profile
    29                             def app_user_detail(request, slug=None):
    30     83.3 MiB      0.1 MiB       university_obj = Universities.objects.using('cms').filter(deleted=0, status=1, verified=1)
    31     83.3 MiB      0.0 MiB       ids = [4, 5]
    32     83.3 MiB      0.0 MiB       master_user_types = MasterUserTypes.objects.using("cms").filter(~Q(id__in=ids)).all()
    33     83.3 MiB      0.0 MiB       gc.isenabled()
    34     83.3 MiB      0.0 MiB       gc.collect()
    35     83.3 MiB      0.0 MiB       return render(request, 'templates/news_managment/news_dashboard_detail.html',
    36     89.0 MiB      5.7 MiB                     {'slug': slug, 'university_obj': university_obj, 'master_user_types': master_user_types})
```

Suppose,i have 89.0 Mib right now for this function but when i refresh it the size will increase.I am running the django project on localhost

Comment: What is your `DEBUG` setting set to?

Comment: Where does `@profile` come from or how does it look like?

Comment: @KrzysztofSzularz  `DEBUG=TRUE` and profiler displays line by line memory consuption and it is imported in proeject like this.`from memory_profiler import profile`

Comment: Try without the `DEBUG`. Django keeps various references in this mode.